# How to handle exception in spark scala for withcolumn and continue to remaining records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a column to a spark dataframe using `withColumn` in scala,

Since the dataset is huge, my `withColumn` is failing at a specific record,

I am trying to write this in `try-catch`, so that I catch the exception and log those bad records and continue the remaining records.

Is there a way in spark-scala to handle exceptions that occur in `withColumn` ?

Please suggest.

Comment: I think try - catch is not the best practice in scala especially when you work with the data; could you share code and error you have?

Answer (score 3):

Using Try,Success,Failure will solve the above problem.Assuming that udf is used.

Sample data frame :

```
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|year|country|state|college|marks|Num|
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|2019|  India|    B|     BC|   65|  2|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UC|   15|  2|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UC|   65|  2|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UD|   45|  0|
|2019|    USA|    B|     UC|   44|  2|
|2019|    USA|    B|     MC|   88|  2|
|2019|    USA|    B|     MC|   90|  2|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   65|  2|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   33|  2|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   55|  2|
|2020|  India|    A|     AD|   70|  2|
|2020|  India|    B|     AC|   88|  2|
|2020|  India|    B|     AC|   60|  2|
|2020|  India|    B|     BC|   45|  2|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UC|   85|  2|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UC|   55|  2|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UD|   32|  0|
|2020|    USA|    B|     UC|   64|  2|
|2020|    USA|    B|     MC|   78|  2|
|2020|    USA|    B|     MC|   80|  2|
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+
```

We will divide col("marks") by col("Num") , in cases where col("Num")=0 we will get an arithmetic exception.

The following udf will be used:

```
def myUdf = udf((i: Int, j: Int) => { 
  def test(ii: Int, jj: Int): Try[Int] = Try {
    val q = ii/jj
    q
  }

  test(i, j) match { 
    case Success(lines) => lines.toString
    case _ => null
  }
})
```

Followed by :
`ad_df_1.withColumn("finalCol",myUdf(col("marks"),col("Num")))`

The output data frame will have null value in cases where division by zero exception has occurred.

Final output:

```
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+--------+
|year|country|state|college|marks|Num|finalCol|
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+--------+
|2019|  India|    B|     BC|   65|  2|      32|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UC|   15|  2|       7|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UC|   65|  2|      32|
|2019|    USA|    A|     UD|   45|  0|    null|
|2019|    USA|    B|     UC|   44|  2|      22|
|2019|    USA|    B|     MC|   88|  2|      44|
|2019|    USA|    B|     MC|   90|  2|      45|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   65|  2|      32|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   33|  2|      16|
|2020|  India|    A|     AC|   55|  2|      27|
|2020|  India|    A|     AD|   70|  2|      35|
|2020|  India|    B|     AC|   88|  2|      44|
|2020|  India|    B|     AC|   60|  2|      30|
|2020|  India|    B|     BC|   45|  2|      22|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UC|   85|  2|      42|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UC|   55|  2|      27|
|2020|    USA|    A|     UD|   32|  0|    null|
|2020|    USA|    B|     UC|   64|  2|      32|
|2020|    USA|    B|     MC|   78|  2|      39|
|2020|    USA|    B|     MC|   80|  2|      40|
+----+-------+-----+-------+-----+---+--------+
```